# Subnets are not getting created while using Powershell Az commands

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network

I have below PowerShell script to create `vnet` and `subnet` in Azure

```
 $virtualNetworkName = 'corp-northeurope-vnet'
 $frontendSubnetName = 'frontendsubnet'
 $vNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/26"
 $SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.1.0/28"


 $virtualNetwork = Get-AzVirtualNetwork -Name $virtualNetworkName -ResourceGroupName $rgName
if ($null -eq $virtualNetwork) {
    $virtualNetwork = New-AzVirtualNetwork `
        -Name $virtualNetworkName `
        -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
        -AddressPrefix $vNetAddressPrefix `
        -Location $location 
}
else {
    Write-Log -Message "[$($virtualNetwork.Name)] already exists"
}


$fesubnet = Get-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name $frontendSubnetName -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork
if ($null -eq $fesubnet) {
    $fesubnet = Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig `
        -Name $frontendSubnetName `
        -AddressPrefix $subnetAddressPrefix `
        -VirtualNetwork $virtualNetwork

    $virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork
}
else {
    Write-Log -Message "[$($fesubnet.Name)] already exists"
}
```

But It does not work.

Error throws here

> $virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork

> Subnet 'frontendsubnet' is not valid in virtual network 'corp-northeurope-vnet'. StatusCode: 400 ReasonPhrase: Bad Request ErrorCode: NetcfgInvalidSubnet ErrorMessage: Subnet 'frontendsubnet' is
> | not valid in virtual network 'corp-northeurope-vnet'. OperationID : 06c1ed77-14f1-294d-a19a-41c2epbdd04f

Is it anything to do with IP Range ?

Comment: @Theo  yes typo. i have changed vnet and subnet names in this question just for security reasons.

Comment: Have you changed the IP ranges to something random? That subnet would not fall within the VNET given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by your subnet address prefix. When your VNet address prefix is 10.0.0.0/26. Then your subnet addresses range should be less than **10.0.0.0/26**. You can change the subnet prefix as **10.0.0.0/28**. Then it will be no problem.

Comment: short and sweet answer. Is there any tool which can help me to give the subnet addresses if I specify the number of subnets required?

Comment: @kudlatiger The best way is to learn about the network address space. If you know it well, then you can solve all the familiar issues like this later. Take a look at the [subnet](https://subnet.ninja/how-to-subnet/). And if the answer solves your problem and do you mind accepting it?

Comment: Done.  I wish there is an option in StackOverflow to choose multiple answers. Even @Daniel provided a hint towards the solution.

Answer (score 2):

The IP Range of the subnet is not within the IP Range of the VNET this causes the Subnet configuration to be invalid.

So either you change the Subnet address prefix to be within the VNETs Address Prefix or you expand the VNETs address prefix so that it includes the range of the Subnet you are trying to create.

A good tool to use to plan your IP Address Prefixes is: http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=10.0.0.0&mask1=26&mask2=

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the issue. However, tool specified does not provide the exact subnet address range for the VNET.

Comment: @kudlatiger The tool will give you a correct output if you put in your values. That tool is used by millions of people world wide to calculate their Address Spaces. You put in a IP address and the netmask. eg. 10.0.0.0 / 24 and it will give you the output with the max and min host address in that range

Comment: @kudlatiger as you can see in the screenshot your /26 gives you the range of 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.62. That is a perfectly correct range. Then what Azure dues is it reservers the first few addresses so the first available address in that range will be 10.0.0.4.

Comment: Appreciate your answer. My question is, is there any tool which accept  input VNET IP range (10.0.0.0/26) and number of subnet, ( 3  ), gives the output as "10.0.0.0/28","10.0.0.16/28" and "10.0.0.32/28"

Comment: @kudlatiger there are tools like this one: http://www.davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html not really the same thing as you are asking for but usually when you create subnets you actually do a guestimate how many addresses you need and then create the subnet in that size, not the other way around.

Comment: appreciated your time, upvoted!  sorry could not accept the answer because Charles provided the direct answer "10.0.0.0/28" which resolved the blocker, however, I also appreciate your time and foundation details, it helped. keep helping the community @Daniel . I wish there is option in stackoverflow to choose multiple answers.

Comment: This tool is cool - davidc.net/sites/default/subnets/subnets.html

Answer (score 0):

One problem is the second command line.

If you are saying you already have created a Vnet, a subnet, a Vnet IP CIDR prefix, and a Subnet IP CIDR prefix, the command for Subnet is Not `$frontendSubnetName`, "Frontend" is the name of the subnet included on Vnet "corp-northeurope-vnet".

```
$frontendSubnetName = 'frontendsubnet'
```

the command frontendSubnetName is the wrong, the correct should be:

```
$subnetConfig = 'frontendsubnet'
```

Try using these commands:

```
$virtualNetworkName = 'corp-northeurope-vnet'
$subnetConfig = 'frontendsubnet'
$vNetAddressPrefix = "10.0.0.0/26"
$SubnetAddressPrefix = "10.0.1.0/28"
```

Here the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/quick-create-powershell